# Does a timer lifecycle end with the death of a process in linux?

Tags: c++, linux, timer, posix

I have a utility library(.so) which does some basic functions and maintains a map of active Timers.There is a crash observed during cleanup of map using [] operator.I will add the check for map member validity but one thing hit me....Do Linux / posix timers die when the process that created them dies???This timer is cleaned up at exit time.I can just ignore stopping the timer or Linux Kernel takes care of it.

Comment: How would you refer to the timer from another process to clean it up?

Comment: I don't see what difference that makes. Where would you put the cleanup code if you want to deal with this? If the process crashes, the library can't do anything.